# How to type `C-M-\`

Tags: key-bindings

How to type <kbd>C-M</kbd>?

Particularly, I am after this command -

[image]

from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html

**First attempt**

1. Select the text
2. Use the combination <kbd>Ctrl-Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Alt GR</kbd> but I don't see any effect.

**Second attempt**

1. Select the text
2. Press at the same time keys marked with a red square on the keyboard map
   [image]
   No effect

By asking a key description (type  <kbd>C-h k</kbd> followed by the relevant key combination) I really get the correct reference:

[image]

but why I don't see any indentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to type S-<LEFT>](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/how-to-type-s-left)

Comment: "I try the combination Ctrl-Alt and Ctrl-Alt GR but I don't see any effect" -- did you type Ctrl-Alt-\ (being the key sequence you asked about), or just Ctrl-Alt (which does nothing in Emacs).

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot -- you've understood correctly, so something else is going wrong here.  If you type `C-h k` emacs *should* prompt you in the minibuffer with "Describe the following key".  If you then try typing `C-M-\ ` again, what does Emacs tell you?

Comment: @phils, I really get the correct reference, but I don't get the indentation. See update of my question.

Comment: Ok, so this question has been successfully answered, and you should post your new question separately. @jdtonkin's answer is correct and is working for you, so you should probably Accept it. In the new question you should show us exactly what text you are trying to indent, and tell us which major mode the buffer is in.

Comment: The text will only be indented if it isn't already indented as far as Emacs thinks it should be. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html#Indentation

Comment: You can indent a region by pressing TAB, when the region is active.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Where did you get Emacs from, which version exactly? What keyboard layout are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`C-M-\` requires all three keys to be held at the same time, not like `C-M \`. So, in your case, that's `Ctrl-Alt-\` all together.

Comment: I am unsuccessful in applying your solution. See update of my question.

Comment: This is bound to `indent-region`: have you selected a region?