# How to type S-<LEFT> during indent-rigidly?

Tags: key-bindings

How to type <kbd>S-LEFT</kbd> during the transient mode after `C-x <TAB>` (`indent-rigidly`)?

Particularly, I am after [this command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html)

> `C-x <TAB>`
>
> This command is used to change the indentation of all lines that begin in the region, moving the affected lines as a rigid unit.
>   If called with no argument, the command activates a transient mode for adjusting the indentation of the affected lines interactively. While this transient mode is active, typing `<LEFT>` or `<RIGHT>` indents leftward and rightward, respectively, by one space. You can also type `S-<LEFT>` or `S-<RIGHT>` to indent leftward or rightward to the next tab stop (see Tab Stops). Typing any other key disables the transient mode, and resumes normal editing.

In the above example is  <kbd>`S - <LEFT>`</kbd>  preceded by  <kbd>C- x</kbd> ?

Particularly, the steps I follow:

1. Select the text
2. Type <kbd>C-X</kbd>

[image]

3. Type <kbd>Shift - left arrow</kbd> (is it indifferent whether to type left or right shift?)

[image]

The result is some other window opened, e.g. *scratch* and no indentation done. The key combination thus obtained is <kbd>C-x right</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Please take some time to work through the tutorial. Type `C-h t` which means hold down `Ctrl` while typing `h`, and then (without Ctrl) type `t`.

Comment: "In the above example is S - LEFT preceded by C- x ?" -- It's preceded by `C-x <TAB>`, just like the documentation you've shown tells you.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using GUI emacs rather than running it in a terminal, as your terminal most likely can't send shifted arrow sequences.

Comment: I open emacs with `-nw` if I understand your question correctly

Comment: Don't use `-nw`.  When you use `-nw` you lose access to certain key sequences, because terminals can't send all the sequences that Emacs understands, which will only make troubleshooting harder. Until you have things working, stick with the GUI version.

Comment: @phils, that doesn't seem an option to me as I work remotely and using the GUI is very slow over a remote connection.

Comment: you might investigate using Emacs locally, and opening your remote files via TRAMP. These limits network access to loading and saving the files, the rest of your interactions happen on your local machine.

Comment: Understood -- I usually do the same when working remotely. You definitely want to read about the Tramp feature of Emacs, which lets you seamlessly access remote files from a local Emacs.  It's still slower, but it may work well enough that you don't mind.

Comment: Regardless of Tramp, for *troubleshooting* purposes, you should definitely install GUI emacs on your local machine, so that if something doesn't work in the terminal/remote emacs instance, you can *check* what the documentation is telling you in your local GUI instance, which will tell you whether the problem is with the terminal or with your interpretation of the documentation.

Comment: @phils, I opened emacs GUI on my local machine and still the key combination I get is C-x right instead of C-x Shift-right. So apparently there is something else I don't understand how to get the sequence.

Comment: @phils, but now I noticed your comment that the combination should be C-x-TAB Shift-leftarrow. That made the successful indentation. That is the answer.

Comment: Again, see what `C-h k` followed by `S-<right>` tells you (and note that the canonical description is actually `<S-right>` so I would expect you to see that).  Emacs might say something like "<right> (translated from <S-right>)" in which case you would still know that Emacs saw the shifted-sequence.

Comment: The manual distinguishes between notation for physical keyboard keys and the (logical) key-sequence notation that Emacs itself uses, in Help. For the keyboard key, the manual writes `S-<RIGHT>`. For the key sequence Emacs help writes `<S-right>`. Note the difference in position of the angle brackets and the position of the Shift modifier. And note the overall highlighting, which is shown differently even here, on Stack Exchange. (I can't show the highlighting difference in comments here.) For 99% of your interaction with Emacs you will see only key-sequence notation, not physical-key notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S-` means hold down the shift key, `<left>` is the left-arrow key.

see the manual for [details](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html#User-Input)

The complete sequence is:

<kbd>`C-x <TAB> S-<LEFT>`</kbd>

In emacs version **23.1.1** after you press

<kbd>`C-x <TAB>`</kbd>

the indentation of block is made rigidly by one space and you are not prompted to supply <kbd>`S-<LEFT>`</kbd>.

In emacs version **24.5.1** after pressing <kbd>`C-x <TAB>`</kbd> you are prompted to supply arguments:

```
Indent region with <left>, <right>, <S-left>, or <S-right>.
```

After typing <kbd>`S-<LEFT>`</kbd> the indentation is done by a <kbd>TAB</kbd> and by a space when pressing <kbd>`<LEFT>`</kbd>.

See also [C-x-TAB not followed by options](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43740/c-x-tab-not-followed-by-options?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @Viesturs Also remember that Shift is (very appropriately) the *upper-case* `S-`, so that you don't confuse it with Super (which is *lower-case* `s-`.

Comment: I am unsuccessful in applying your solution. I explained the problems in the update of my question.

Comment: May be you can include in your answer the complete key sequence C-x-TAB S-rightarrow to minimise confustion?

Comment: whether or not you're using `indent-rigidly`, you enter `S-<LEFT>` the same way