# C-x-TAB not followed by options

Tags: key-bindings

I am after the key-binding <kbd>C-x-TAB</kbd> <kbd>S-rightarrow</kbd> to indent each line in a block by a TAB see - https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html.

I always open emacs in the `-nw` mode. On my local computer (Emacs 24.5.1) when I press <kbd>C-x-TAB</kbd> I am asked for the arguments to this command:

[image]

but on a remote computer (Emacs 24.3.1) the arguments are not asked for and indentation is done immediately with a space.

The goal is to have indentation with a TAB. What is going wrong on the remote computer and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a remote computer (Emacs 24.3.1) the arguments are not asked for and
>   indentation is done immediately with a space.
>
> The goal is to have indentation with a TAB. What is going wrong on the
>   remote computer and how to fix?

Upgrade Emacs on the remote compute to 24.4 or better, see etc/NEWS (<kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd></kbd>):

```
* Editing Changes in Emacs 24.4

*** The behavior of `C-x TAB' (`indent-rigidly') has changed.
When invoked without a prefix argument, it now activates a transient
mode in which typing <left>, <right>, <S-left>, and <S-right> adjusts
the text indentation in the region.  Typing any other key resumes
normal editing behavior.
```

Alternatively, try backporting these patches (I picked these out with `git log --grep=indent-rigidly`, I'm not 100% sure these are only applicable ones):

- [`77221051a2` 2013-12-21 Tweak C-x TAB behavior changes, and update docs.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=77221051a20d22ab785b0e0441a320862ec589a0)
- [`642eb8b6af` 2013-10-17 * lisp/indent.el (indent-rigidly): Fix 2013-10-08 change.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=642eb8b6afa1c16b134d296ed90fd8fe59dc1d49)
- [`b7d5bd823c` 2013-10-08 * indent.el: Provide interactive indent-rigidly mode.](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=b7d5bd823c239a8ee3613abcc4e24fe290a673d0)

Comment: I'd suggest strongly that the OP should *not* try to apply the individual patches. Upgrading emacs is a much safer option (of course, the OP might not have rights to update emacs on the remote machine, but in that case, he/she would probably not have rights to apply patches either).

Comment: @NickD "probably not have rights to apply patches" - you could apply the patches to a copy of indent.el, and then load the patched indent.el in your config. Doesn't sound too dangerous to me: if it doesn't work, throw away the patched indent.el, no harm done.

Comment: it wouldn't be too dangerous to you, but OP is having trouble with basic directions from the manual. Given the confusion expressed in several questions posted in quick succession, over-writing built-in functions in their config is likely to create more problems